# Error trying to Update List Items via a TimerJob

Tags: timer-jobs

I thought I could reference SPContext when executing the timerjob function but I get "Instance reference is not set to an instance of an object".  It fails when I reference SPContext.

What am I doing wrong?  (I'm trying to update items in a list using a TimerJob)

```
Public Overrides Sub Execute(ByVal targetInstanceId As Guid)

   Dim oWeb As SPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web
   oWeb.Site.OpenWeb("http://dept.litwareinc.com/npp/NPE")

   'Update PEEIT Employees List
   UpdatePEEITEmployees(oWeb)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

SPContext is not accessible in timer job. The SharePoint timer service is a windows service.  So you should pass a site and web Ids(Urls) to the timer job and open new web.

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId)){using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId)) { //code }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SPContext` represents the context of a `HTTPRequest` (Similar to `HTTPContext`).

In the Execute method, `SPWebApplication` instance is available ; get the target site instance from the `this.WebApplication.Sites` collection.

URL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686%28v=office.12%29.aspx